# Multiple web security causing ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: spring-security, jwt, spring-social-google

I'm trying to configure Spring Security via Java Config to handle two kinds of authentication on my app: form based (user login) and token based (REST api).

The form configuration is straighforward, except the part where I had to create my own `SecuritySocialConfigurer` (basically a copy of `SpringSocialConfigurer` with a custom authentication success handler that generates a JWT token and sets a cookie with it in the response).

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    super.configure(auth);
    auth
        .userDetailsService(userDetailsService())
        .passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/css/**", "/img/**");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/signin")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/signin/authenticate")
            .failureUrl("/signin?param.error=bad_credentials")
        .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/signout")
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**", "favicon.ico", "/public/**", "/auth/**", "/signin/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER")
        .and()
            .rememberMe()
        .and()
            .apply(new MilesSocialSecurityConfigurer());
}
```

When only this configuration is in play, I'm able to access `http://localhost:8080` and be redirected to `http://localhost:8080/signin` to perform signin. After successful signin I check that the JWT token cookie is present.

The second security config purpose is to check the presence of the JWT token when the REST api is called.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .addFilterAfter(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .antMatcher("/api/**")
            .csrf()
                .disable()
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("favicon.ico", "/public/**", "/auth/**", "/signin/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
        ;
}

@Bean
public JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
    JwtAuthenticationFilter filter = new JwtAuthenticationFilter("/api/**");
    filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(jwtAuthenticationSuccessHandler);
    filter.setAuthenticationManager(apiAuthenticationManager());
    return filter;
}

@Bean
public ProviderManager apiAuthenticationManager() {
    return new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(jwtAuthenticationProvider));
}
```

`JwtAuthenticationProvider` is a class that parses a JWT token and generates an `UserDetails` object or throws an `AuthenticationException` if a token does not exist or is invalid.

When this second config is in place, I'm unable to navigate to `http://localhost:8080` (or `/signin`) to initiate the signin proccess - the browser returns a ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

I tried some things without any success. Any clue about what is going on would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
.antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
```

to

```
 .anyRequest().authenticated()
```

This means any URL that doesn't match what you have explicitly defined will require authentication.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not solve the problem. I still have ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS when trying to access any app URL.